# linq skip count when count is zero

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a linq-to-sql query and I wish the LastOrDefault operator were available but it's not. So, I'm writing the query like this:

```
TheUserNote = ((from note in MyDC.UserNotes
  where note.UserID == TheUserID
  select note.NoteText).Skip(
    (from n in MyDC.UserNotes
     where n.UserID == TheUserID
     select n.NoteID).Count() - 1)).SingleOrDefault(),
```

Basically, I want to use Skip and Count to get to the last item: count how many items there are, substract 1, and skip for that number.
It's not working and I'm looking to fix it. The problem is that sometimes Count can be 0 so I get an error saying parameters are not valid since in that case Count will be -1.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make the count it's own variable? and check for > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try `.Reverse().FirstOrDefault()`, or if you have a date column or primary key column try `.OrderByDescending(...).FirstOrDefault()`.

Using your variable names and comment:

```
var TheUserNote
    = MyDC
    .UserNotes
    .Where(x => x.UserId == TheUserID)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.NoteDateTime)
    .FirstOrDefault()
;
```

Comment: Reverse is not supported in linq-to-sql

Comment: Aye, you're right. But OrderByDescending(...).FirstOrDefault() is. :)

Comment: Edited for brevity and clarity.

Comment: What parameter do I put in: I have note.NoteDateTime that's the sort key. How do I format the parameter?

Comment: Updated to include lambda and original variable names.

Comment: Sorry to be stuck on this syntax; I'm using query syntax instead of method syntax and the lambda doesn't work: I don't have x.NoteDateTime available.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific order they are coming back in? I assume so otherwise why would it matter if it was the last or the first one you got?

Can't you just order by whatever in the opposite direction and use FirstOrDefault?

Comment: I try "orderby descending note.NoteDatetime" and the keyword descending is underlined red with "Invalid expression term". When I remove the descending keyword, the red underline is gone. Seen that before?

Comment: I think the syntax is orderby note.NoteDatetime descending